# Swift + Created PDF file using binary data

Tags: swift

I am trying to create pdf file using binary data(Which is receiving from OData service).

I am using below code to generate file, data transfer is working fine. However a damaged file is getting created.

```
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first{
        let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(im_filename)
        print(fileURL)
            do{
                let pdfData = Data(bytes: gDocumentOutputData, count: gDocBinarySize)
                try pdfData.write(to: fileURL)
                }catch{
                    print("cant write…")
            }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is `iDocOutputData`? Consider that `Data` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so in a loop `each` is a single byte.

Comment: why do you `base64Encoded` each.data?

Comment: Show how you have converted the original image into a Base64-encoded string.

Comment: I could see my answer was not of any use, so I deleted it. I think 
you are trying to create a pdf document with non-pdf document data.

Comment: I am using the same data to download at local pdf file using SAP side functionality. Which is working fine and able to see PDF file. Now I am sending the same byte data as response of OData service and fetching from IOS side. Agenda is to display same PDF inside a webview.

Comment: Hi @workingdog, thanks for your support. I have made some changes to back-end logic to convert Byte data to Base64. Now I am able to create the pdf file.